# Java, LibGDX locks my game at 30 frames per second

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm using LibGDX for game development in Java.

I've done extensive searching on Google to find a solution to the problem, but what I've found is that most people actually don't have their game locked and want it locked.

Here's the configuration code I'm using

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
...
config.width = 960;
config.height = 768;
config.backgroundFPS = 60;
config.foregroundFPS = 60;
config.vSyncEnabled = false;
...
```

I also tried setting `backgroundFPS` and `foregroundFPS` to 0.

If I set it to 20 it actually limits the game to 20fps. Is there any solution to this?

I know it's not doing too much work, because I tested the game loop with nothing but the framerate logger and it still sticks to 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**-1.** If you are using fpsLogger, try using the code in step 2 or Fraps.

**0.** Disable Vsync or enable it.

**1.** Fraps can be problematic sometimes, in case you are using it. It occasionally shows me 30 fps when it is not.

**2.** Print `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()` to find out your real fps.

**3.** Don't set backgroundFPS and foregroundFPS.

**4.** Make sure you are not using `Thread.sleep()` function. You might put it before and forgot about it.

**5.** Reboot your computer. If you really cannot find the source of the problem, this might help. Maybe your computer is tired or there is a problem with graphics driver.

**6.** Try it on another system. This problem might be caused by your setup.

**7.** To see if the problem is in your computer or your project, make a fresh project and measure its fps.

Comment: 0. I've done that.
1. I don't know what Fraps is
2. I checked that and it also showed 30. I can even notice the framerate with my own eyes
3. That's how I started off. I only was setting them because the framerate was slow.
4. I'm not using that anywhere.
5. That doesn't seem to have worked
6. I'll have to try that, but my computer is a gaming laptop and this is a 2D game project with barely anything in it at the moment.
7. I actually removed absolutely everything but the base class that extends Game, it still was limited to 30 frames per second.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the program on somebody else's computer and it ran at 60fps without any trouble.

It turns out my computer was using integrated graphics instead of my high performance graphics card. After forcing Java to use the graphics card it now runs at 60fps.